# Variable sized arrays and array pointer in C

Tags: c

I am doing coding exercise in HackerRank. In the Variable Sized Arrays exercise of C++, I tried to do it with C, but I couldn't get it right.

My code sometimes pass the simple test case 0, but sometimes not. The code was exactly the same but came out with different answer.

```
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

    int n, q;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &q);

    int *p_arr[n];

    if (n > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <  n; i++) {
            int tmp;
            scanf("%d", &tmp);

            int tmp_arr[tmp];
            p_arr[i] = tmp_arr;
            for (int j = 0; j < tmp; j++) {
                int value;
                scanf("%d", &value);
                p_arr[i][j] = value;
                printf("%d ", p_arr[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    if (q > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            int row, col;
            scanf("%d%d", &row, &col);
            printf ("%d %d\n", row, col);
            int answer = p_arr[row][col];
            printf("%d\n", answer);

        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This was the wrong answer I got

```
1 5 4 

1 2 8 9 3 

0 1

21973

1 3

32764
```

I didn't know where the `21973` and `32764` came from.

This was the answer I expected

```
1 5 4 

1 2 8 9 3 

0 1

5

1 3

9
```

Sometimes I got the wrong answer, sometimes I got the correct. Why was that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Variable Sized Arrays exercise of C++` is an oxymoron, C++ doesn't provides "Variable Length Arrays" except through non-standard compiler extensions.

Comment: I think it would help if you shared the exercise description as well.

Comment: `int tmp_arr[tmp]` goes out of scope at the end of the `for` loop. What you assign to `p_arr[i] = tmp_arr;` no longer exists outside the loop.

Comment: `int tmp_arr[tmp];` is an array on the stack, its lifetime ends with its scope, so it is gone in the next iteration and accessing it in the next for loop with `int answer = p_arr[row][col];` is undefined behavior. Change it to `int *tmp_arr = malloc(tmp * sizeof *tmp_arr);`

Comment: You need to do `scanf("%d%d", &n, &q); if(n <= 0) halt_and_catch_fire(); int *p_arr[n];`. You can't declare an array with size zero in C, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: `"Sometimes I got the wrong answer, sometimes I got the correct. Why was that?"` See: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Yes, correct that is what I meant. Sorry for the confusion. It was the assignment to `p_arr[i]` that would ultimately be the issue. Do you not see `int answer = p_arr[row][col];` in the `for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)`?

Comment: It is used in the `for` loop following `if (q > 0)` which is in an entirely different scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, if the exercise involves a Variable Length Array, then it should be written in C because the C++ standard does not provide VLAs (and they have been made optional beginning in C11 after being added with C99)

The primary problem with your code (aside from a complete failure to allocate the inputs) is that it invokes *Undefined Behavior* because `int tmp_arr[tmp]` goes out of scope at the end of the `for` loop. What you assign with `p_arr[i] = tmp_arr;` no longer exists outside the loop because `tmp_arr` no longer exists. Any attempt to access a value after it has gone out of scope invokes *Undefined Behavior*, see [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Every time you handle input, you must ***validate*** the input succeeded and the value obtained is within a valid range. For instance both `n` and `q` must be positive values. Using `scanf` you could do (minimally)

```
    if (scanf("%d%d", &n, &q) != 2 || n <= 0 || q <= 0) {
        fputs ("error: invalid format or value.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

The above validates that 2 inputs were received and that both are positive values.

In order to preserve the pointer assigned with `p_arr[i] = tmp_arr;`, `tmp_arr` must be an allocated type to handle an unknown `tmp` number of elements, or it must be declared outside the loop (and large enough to handle all anticipated values -- which given that `tmp` is read as input -- doesn't seem like the intended approach). You cannot declare `tmp_arr` static either as there would only be one instance and assigning it repeatedly to `p_arr[i]` would leave all elements of `p_arr[i]` pointing to the same place.

Simply allocate for `tmp_arr` and then the assignment to `p_arr[i]` will survive for the life of the program or until it is freed, e.g.

```
        int *tmp_arr = calloc (tmp, sizeof *tmp_arr);   /* allocate */
        if (!tmp_arr) {                 /* validate every allocation */
            perror ("calloc-tmp_arr");
            return 1;
        }
        p_arr[i] = tmp_arr;
```

(**note:** `calloc` was used above to zero the new memory allocated. You can use `malloc` instead since the code assigns to each element)

Putting it altogether and adding (minimal) validation, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    int n, q;   /* validate EVERY input */
    if (scanf("%d%d", &n, &q) != 2 || n <= 0 || q <= 0) {
        fputs ("error: invalid format or value.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    int *p_arr[n];  /* array of n-pointers to int */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int tmp;
        if (scanf("%d", &tmp) != 1 || tmp <= 0) {   /* validate! */
            fputs ("error: invalid input - tmp.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        int *tmp_arr = calloc (tmp, sizeof *tmp_arr);   /* allocate */
        if (!tmp_arr) {                 /* validate every allocation */
            perror ("calloc-tmp_arr");
            return 1;
        }
        p_arr[i] = tmp_arr;
        for (int j = 0; j < tmp; j++) {
            int value;
            if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {     /* validate! */
                fputs ("error: invalid input - value.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            p_arr[i][j] = value;
            printf ("%d ", p_arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');     /* no need to printf a single-character */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int row, col;   /* validate! */
        if (scanf ("%d%d", &row, &col) != 2 || row < 0 || col < 0) {
            fputs ("error: invalid input, row or col.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        printf ("%d %d\n%d\n", row, col, p_arr[row][col]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free (p_arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**Note:** untested as no hackerrank input was provided)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your coding!